# Re-bundle on changes with Docker or PM2

Tags: docker, webpack, pm2

So I've deployed an app to a remote server. The app is quite large, so I've made some production configs for bundling the client files with webpack.

Currently I'm running the server with docker-compose, and in the server-container I'm running pm2-docker (as there are some workers that needs to be run).

To bundle the client, I'm just using a command like `npm run build`, so I'm wondering how I could rebuild the client whenever I push changes to the remote server.

To duck it down: whenever there is changes, do `npm run build`

What would be the best way to do this? Are you able to run some kind of command specified in the PM2-.yml-file or in the docker-compose .yml-file?

Thankful for any help!

Comment: I’d advise you to not install software in a running container, but put `npm run build` in your `Dockerfile` (and push the built image to a registry server, and pull it on the remote systems).  Is that a path you’ve investigated?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to push the image to public registry (and can't pay for it to be private). Possibly if I'm able to save the image locally and push the image to the remote server